# Tableau - Highest level of Subscription

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get one field in Tableau based on the user to count only the highest level of Subscription he has purchased.

Eg: Username - A, he has purchased a subscription say Premium. As a premium he has access to the standard and Basic which is below the premium. Now under the user it shows he has access to Premium, standard, Basic. But i want to see him as premium(as this is the highest) how do i calculate this.

Thanks,
Sangeetha

Comment: In order to increase your chances to receive a answer you should show your efforts to solve the issue, for example some piece of code that doesn't work as expected.